# Saving test results to a database: keeping the database neat

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a test system using Wordpress, jQuery and PHP which is working great. The area that I don't have much experience in is mysql databases.

I'm not really sure how to save the results in a neat and tidy way.

The things I want to save are the following:

1. Users name.
2. Test name.
3. Questions.
4. Answers.
5. Score.
6. Pass/fail.

Points 1, 2, 5 & 6 are fairly straight forward to save the data. The confusion comes with the questions and answers.

**How can I save these in a neat way to the mysql database?**

Say there are 10 questions, each with multiple choice answers, how can I save each of those in the database but have it linked to the user that filled them in? I'm not sure how to keep the database neat and this could quickly spiral out of control.

In the future I may want to do some searching on the those questions and answers.

Comment: Neat way? Are you asking us to normalize your database for you?

Comment: @BenM As I'm not massively familiar with mysql I was wondering if it can all be done in one table. I wasn't asking for someone to do it for me.

Comment: Yes, it can all be stored in a single table. Should it be? No! Heed some of the tips in the answer by @duffymo and do your research into relational database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize your database structure.

```
**Table: users**
id - int
username - varchar
password - varchar
active - enum (y,n)

**Table: questions**
id - int
question - varchar/text

**Table: answers**
id - int
question_id - int (foreign key questions.id)
answer - varchar/text
is_correct_anser - enum (y, n)

**Table: test_master**
id - int
test_name - varchar/text
pass_score - int (minimum score required to pass the test)

**Table: test**
user_id - int (foreign key to users.id)
test_id - int (foreign key to test_master.id)
question_id - int (foreign key to questions.id)
answer_id - int (foreign key to answers.id)
```

Based on above tables, you can store all required information in in normalized way. Please note that, normalization will not always help and it depends on your application's requirement. It is also a better ideal to store total score in a separate table along with user_id and test_id once test is completed as this will avoid joins on multiple table.

Comment: Ok great, definitely gives me a direction to go in - I guess the real answer is to split the tables up into several.

Answer (score 4):

"Neat" should make you think "normalization".

Start thinking about the relationships and don't worry about tables for now.  You've already articulated some of them:

- questions have one or more answers
- one or more answers for a given question can be considered "correct"
- tests have one or more questions
- a test has one score and one name
- a user can take zero or more tests
- a test can be taken by zero or more users
- a question can appear on zero or more tests (?)

Once you have those sorted out the tables are relatively easy to describe.

Comment: Ok great, so it's more than likely a at least 2 tables and linking them together with the user's name? As I'm not great with mysql I was wondering if it could all be done in one table but that doesn't appear possible as each question would need a new row.

Comment: No, there's lots more than 2 tables.  You really don't get this, do you?  Sure you can put everything in one table.  Try it and see.  You'll learn pretty quickly why people normalize.  One table is your idea of "neat"?  Good luck with that.

Comment: Probably not no! Wordpress is driving the questions and answers so it's just what the user fills in that needs to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

create one table question in this you have question_id,question and choice. in the ohter table you need to save only the question_id,choice,username,score,testname and so on. the question_id will be the primary key questions table.